# Change font size of titles from facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Reproducible example

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A=rep(c("good","bad"),each=8),
                 B=rep(c("yes","no"),4),
                 C=sample(1:20,16),
                 stringsAsFactors=F) %>%
      group_by(A,B)
```

#### Question

**I'd like to change the font size of the titles from `facet_wrap` ('bad' 'good')**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=B, y=C)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme( axis.text = element_text( size = 14 ),
         axis.text.x = element_text( size = 20 ),
         axis.title = element_text( size = 16, face = "bold" ),
         legend.position="none" )
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just change the actual variable with something like `df$A <- stringr::str_to_title(df$A)`?

Comment: Ah... sorry. Misunderstood what you were wanting.

Comment: Not a problem...I've done it countless times

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Set `strip.text` in the `theme`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=B, y=C)) +
    geom_violin() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1) +
    theme_classic() + 
    theme( axis.text = element_text( size = 14 ),
           axis.text.x = element_text( size = 20 ),
           axis.title = element_text( size = 16, face = "bold" ),
           legend.position="none",
           # The new stuff
           strip.text = element_text(size = 20))
```

Comment: That did it...I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks!